# curve fitting with a date object

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, curve-fitting, derivative

My goal is to calculate the slope of a curve.

I read that I can take the first derivation for this. Which in turn requires a formula that describes my data. So I am looking into curve fits rigth now, but can not find anything that describes how to fit curves properly with date objects in them.

My data are measurements taken at irregular time intervals, and is just incrementing at different rates, but lets ignore this for now, as it makes stuff even more complicated and I am looking for the basics.
The data can be represented by the economics dataset from ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(date, pce))+
  geom_area()
```

[image: economics dataset plotted date and pce]

**Main question**
How to take the first derivation of a curve fit containing date objects? Can I just convert them to a numeric, and will this distort the result?

Fitting a linear model works, but for fit2, I will get an error.

```
fit1 <- lm(pce ~ date, data = economics)
fit2 <- lm(pce ~ poly(date, 2, raw = T), data = economics)
```

```
Error in Ops.Date(X, Y, ...) : ^ not defined for "Date" objects
```

**Side question**
Note that I am looking for things like weekly variations. So I need a fit that is very detailed.
`geom_smooth` can effortlessly fit a function to my data even if x-axis is still in date format, but the `loess` curve or `lm` that I have seen with this will not do the trick for me, as they hide the interesting aspects.
So maybe I am in the wrong place and should use element wise differentation? And if yes, how does it work?
Thank you for helping or giving me resources where I can find the solutions.

Comment: The bottom line is that you lose nothing by converting your dates to numbers and performing regression on them. However, if there is no obvious pattern or model to your time series, you can get the gradient of the curve numerically by simply doing `diff(pce) / diff(as.numeric(date))` (assuming the data are ordered by date). This will give you the gradient of the slope in terms of pce per day, measured at the midpoint between consecutive data points.

Comment: You note that you are "looking for weekly variation." If that's the case, you could just plot your raw data instead. Otherwise, the curve will necessarily smooth to some extent. Meanwhile `lm` and `loess` both can produce as variable of a curve as needed or not (with or without smoothing). If you fit a polynomial equal to the number of data points, you`'ll just get that same plot back basically. Additionally, recognize that the slope of the curve (first derivative) varies at values of date - so you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: One question per question post please: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post Please move the new questions to their own post(s). Your question about derivatives is not a programming question either.

However, look up the definition of the slope: the slope IS the first derivative of y with respect to x. The first derivative is just how y change when x is changed by a tiny amount, i.e. (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h, where h is a small number. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Dates.html) for the `Dates` class, you'll see that it's actually the number of days since January 1, 1970:

> Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates. They are always printed following the rules of the current Gregorian calendar, even though that calendar was not in use long ago (it was adopted in 1752 in Great Britain and its colonies). It is intended that the date should be an integer, but this is not enforced in the internal representation.

Accordingly, you can convert to numeric and include it as a predictor with no issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Date class is just a numeric value
economics$date_num <- as.numeric(economics$date)
economics$date_num[1:40]
#>  [1] -915 -884 -853 -823 -792 -762 -731 -700 -671 -640 -610 -579 -549 -518 -487
#> [16] -457 -426 -396 -365 -334 -306 -275 -245 -214 -184 -153 -122  -92  -61  -31
#> [31]    0   31   59   90  120  151  181  212  243  273

# Fit linear model
lm(pce ~ poly(date_num, 2, raw = T), data = economics) 
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = pce ~ poly(date_num, 2, raw = T), data = economics)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                 (Intercept)  poly(date_num, 2, raw = T)1  
#>                   5.614e+02                    1.960e-01  
#> poly(date_num, 2, raw = T)2  
#>                   3.159e-05
```

We can also include the model directly in `ggplot` using the `formula` argument in `stat_smooth`:

```r
# Plot with quadratic term
ggplot(economics, aes(date_num, pce)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can also just use `lm()` to fit a model. A nice feature of this is that you can specify the dates for which you want slope of the curve, although note that your model is just extrapolating for dates outside of the observed data.

```r
# Fit model
mod <- lm(data = economics, pce ~ poly(date_num,2,raw = T))

# Generate dates for which you want to calculate derivative
new_data <-  data.frame(date_num = -200:200)

# Get predictions for each date, add to data
new_data$pce_pred <- predict(mod,newdata = data.frame(date_num = -200:200))

# Compute derivatives at midpoint, add to data
# NOTE: need to add NA since first is empty
new_data$slope <- c(NA, with(new_data, diff(pce_pred) / diff(date_num)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stat_smooth` function where you can use the method "lm" with your own formula like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics, aes(date, pce))+
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), size = 1) +  
  geom_area(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>